# In a battery grid why does the overall equivalent amf remain the same as the equivalent emf of a single branch and not the resistance?

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel, series

[image]

The Battery grid as shown in the picture above.  When we write down equivalent resistance and emf of each branch { for N such batteries in each branch} then, *[ In this step the battery grid is reduced to branches with M branches of single cell and single resistor}*

**E** *{equivalent of each branch}* **= Ne**  & **R***{equivalent of each branch}***= Nr**, *{ where e & r are the individual emfs & resistances}*

*Now, the next step is to reduce down the circuit into a single cell and a single resistor*,
here in the final step
**E***[equivalent for the circuit}* = **Ne**
**R** *{ equivalent for the circuit}***= Nr/M**
*[ where M is the number of rows in the circuit]*

Now the question is why does the equivalent resistance of the circuit changes to **NR/M** but the equivalent emf of the circuit remains the same as the equivalent emf of each branch **Ne** ?

Picture credits: physics galaxy website